# PHP position output on specific table row

Tags: php, loops, formatting, output

I want to create a log where I have a start/end date and I need to mark (1) the days between that date. The dates can span months, which I already took care of. I just need some help formatting the output so the table accurately represents the data. Data might be exported to Excel later or just printed directly from the browser, that's up for discussion.

Thank you in advance.

```
$i = 1;
$max = 10;
$j = 5;
echo '<table><tr>';
for($i; $i <= $max; $i++){
  echo '<th>' . $i . '</th>';
}
echo '<tr>';
for($j; $j<=$max; $j++){
  echo '<td>1</td>';
}
echo '</tr></table>';
```

This code gets me the following output

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
1 1 1 1 1
```

What I am looking for is for the output to be like this:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
        1 1 1 1 1 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Then you will have to output an empty cell `$max - $j` number of times

```
$i = 1;
$max = 10;
$j = 5;
echo '<table><tr>';
for($i; $i <= $max; $i++){
  echo '<th>' . $i . '</th>';
}
echo '</tr><tr>';

// output empty table sells to right justify the other output
for($x=0; $x<=$max-$j; $x++){
  echo '<td>&nbsp;</td>';
}

for($j; $j<=$max; $j++){
  echo '<td>1</td>';
}
echo '</tr></table>';
```

Comment: Sorry to point out that they have missed the `</tr>` from the header row, which may be worth adding.

Comment: Thanks. I'll play with this, I might still need to figure out a few things but this is a great help.